# Asynchronous Flow only working on create in Debug mode

Tags: visual-workflow, custom-object, asynchronous, debug

I have been working on a roll up flow to sum up a field on a custom object and then update a field on the parent object with that total. However I have used the asynchronous path and while it works when updating the record it only works on creation when running it through the debug mode not on the actual records themselves. Is this a bug with the asynchronous path or am I missing something?

The flow should start when either the interaction object (Child object) is created or updated and the Time Spent Field has changed.

[image: Start of Flow Configuration part 1]

[image: Start of Flow Configuration Part 2]

[image: Flow Path]

Comment: Just to be sure, did you activate the flow?